# Accumulated percentage of change of all previous bars

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Trying to plot the accumulated percentage of change of all previous bars
Getting Error: Getting Undeclared identifier 'accum'

```
indicator("Accumalated Change Percentage")
change = (close - close[1]) / close * 100 // change of current bar in percentage
accum = nz(accum + change)
plot(accum)
```

If I declare accum before using it it doesn't accumulate which is what I am trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//@version=5
indicator("Accumalated Change Percentage")

var float   accum = na

change = ta.change(close) / close * 100
accum := nz(accum + change)

plot(accum)
```

Answer (score 0):

I like the first answer by Bjorn, because it could be adapted to accumulate other operations than just addition, and I am trying to understand how it would produce an cumulative effect.

So far I have been using the [ta.cum](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_ta%7Bdot%7Dcum) build-in function below, which seems to work for its specific purpose of cumulative addition.

```
//@version=5
indicator("Accumulated Change Percentage")
change = ta.change(close) / close * 100
accum = ta.cum(change) 
plot(accum)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).